# PHP/MySQL MIN doesn't return correct price

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table there is values called "auction" and "price"

Something like that:

```
auction | price
1       |   22  
55      |   789
55      |   333 
55      |   666
```

I need select the lowest price of auction 55.

55 the lowest price is 333.
I use this mysql query:

```
$re = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(amount) as amount FROM `bids` WHERE auction = '".$id."'");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($re);
echo $r['amount'];
```

But it returns 789 (the first entry, but not the lowest), why?

Comment: Maybe because you use MIN(amount) and it's called price in your table?

Comment: How's your field defined?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY auction`.

```
mysql_query("SELECT MIN(price) as amount FROM `bids` GROUP MY auction WHERE auction = '".$id."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$re = mysql_query("SELECT MIN(amount) as amount FROM `bids`");
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($re);
echo $r['amount'];
```